# how to use quickfix c++ isSessionTime()

Tags: c++, quickfix

Anyone knows how to use the function bool isSessionTime(const DateTime& time) of quickfix/c++? What I mean is that what should be passed in as the parameter? In the quickfix/J, there is no parameter required, and the function of this method is to predict whether the current time is for a stock session time. But in quickfix/c++, we have to pass parameter, I indeed reviewed the API, and tried pass FIX::DateTime::nowUtc() and FIX::DateTime::nowLocal() to it, but neither of these two works. Both of them will let my program crash. That what makes me confused about what should be passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a [DateTime](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/struct_f_i_x_1_1_date_time.html) object to pass it as a parameter. Have a look at the link and check out your API library files to get a better idea.

Default constructor - initializes to zero.

```
DateTime ()
```

Construct from a Julian day number and time in millis.

```
DateTime (int date, int time)
```

Construct from the specified components.

```
DateTime (int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millis)
```

Comment: Yep, in the quickfix/J, there is no parameter required, and the function of this method is to predict whether the current time is for a stock session time. But in quickfix/c++, we have to pass parameter, I indeed reviewed the API, and tried pass FIX::DateTime::nowUtc() and FIX::DataTime::nowLocal() to it, but neither of these two works. Both of them will let my program crash.

Comment: @Peiti Peter Li - Did you debug it ? Check what values are being passed in the object, when you call nowUtc/nowLocal ? I have a hunch, the correct object is not being passed. As an experiment try creating a **DateTime object** locally and then call the function.

Comment: Ok now I solved the problem. there is a bug in my program. thanks anyway.